# Lenovo V130 Touchpad

Tags: release-juno, touchpad, laptop

Folks, I have the abovementionned laptop but the touchpad is not working. I did find [**a corresponding driver for Windows**](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v130-15ikb/downloads/ds503533) but not for Elementary. Do I have to build  my own kernel here (found [**some pages**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working/) quoting that I need to add an entry to a source file)?

I am using `Juno` and the newer `4.20.generic` kernel but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a known issue on the kernel

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kernel-package/+bug/1789252

You have three options:

1. Demand a good driver for the manufacturer (Lenovo/Elan)
2. Wait for the kernel devs to release one
3. Help the devs (or become one) to release the driver

---

Imagine a Windows without drivers, what you could do. Here at least you have people working in the solution to put it on the kernel, I suggest you to help them at least giving them info and logs if they require

Comment: Thank you, will look into the link provided and might add some code if I got it working.